# Addicted to riddles

Tags: riddle, rhyme

How do you know if you're addicted to riddles?

1.

> I use my head, I move the earth,
>
> So ancient none recall My birth,
>
> One of me spells death and yet,
>
> You'd call me as I am I'll bet,
>
> You know me well, you've got my card,
>
> Who am I? it isn't hard.

2.

> A game of fortune,
>
> Dice will roll,
>
> Name and goal the same,
>
> I have two kinds,
>
> And just one chance,
>
> Can you speak my name?

3.

> A head of thick, wet, braided hair,
>
> I carry more than can be seen,
>
> And in my wake a brightening glare,
>
> A slick, treacherous sheen,
>
> My story short, but often told,
>
> Me in your hands, what would you hold?

4.

> My string tightens as I loose weight,
>
> To remain full, my desired fate,
>
> I can be woven, plastic, skin,
>
> With nothing, coin or fish within,
>
> I travel pressed to many hips,
>
> Surely my name is on your lips?

5.

> A random chance will see you fold,
>
> I am not one for the old,
>
> A vibrant grid to break your back,
>
> Colours Prime I do not lack,
>
> More difficult the more that try,
>
> Can you tell me, what am I?

6.

> I'm something with an antique feel,
>
> A binding, thing to hold and seal,
>
> Breaking me takes no strength,
>
> Just weakness and time of unknown length,
>
> Made by many, kept by few,
>
> Know my name? Speak if you do.

7.

> By clever folk I can be read,
>
> Less clever folk will ask instead,
>
> I stole the likeness of my home,
>
> Else here without direction roam,
>
> Providing clues a familiar game,
>
> So can you tell me, what's my name?

8.

> I'm not a doll on strings,
>
> But my steps are not my own,
>
> Just one hole in such things,
>
> Unless we're torn or blown,
>
> The wind blows now I'll help you see,
>
> Now if you can, you should name me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FULL ANSWER: CREDIT TO EVERYONE**

> 1. Spade (Credit to Reibello)
> 2. Yahtzee (Credit to Jason Horner)
> 3. Mop (Credit to Reibello)
> 4. A Purse (Credit to Mohirl)
> 5. Twister
> 6. An Oath, (Credit to Reibello)
> 7. A Map
> 8. Sock (Credit to hagfy)

The answer of each line spells,

> SYMPTOMS

---

I'm pretty sure #5 is

> Twister.

A random chance will see you fold,

> Refers to the twisting body shapes you make.

I am not one for the old,

> It most certainly is not.

A vibrant grid to break your back

> The game is set up in a grid.

Colours Prime I do not lack,

> The dots are made up of the four basic colors, red, green, yellow, and blue.

More difficult the more that try,

> Twister gets much harder with more people.

I think #7 is

> A map

By clever folk I can be read,

> Because of technology, people don't read maps anymore (which is really a shame, because they can be really useful. Especially when camping.)

Less clever folk will ask instead,

> People will ask for directions.

I stole the likeness of my home,

> Maps resemble the place they are showing.

Else here without direction roam,

> Without a map, you are lost.

Providing clues a familiar game,

> Maps are used for scavenger hunts.

Comment: Getting there 2/8 +1 Joe

Comment: Joe, I think 1 might be Reibello's answer instead of mohirl's; I think that one fits better.

Comment: @El-Guest, oh, you're right.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Nicely done.  I've fixed #6 now.  BNGU

Answer (score 5):

Partial

I think 8 is

> A **SOCK**

I'm not a doll on strings,
But my steps are not my own,

> A sock puppet

Just one hole in such things,

> Socks have a single hole

Unless we're torn or blown,
The wind blows now I'll help you see,

> A ripped sock would have another hole, and a windsock has holes at both ends

Comment: Getting there 1/8 +1

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer

Some of #1 sounds like a description of

> Tarot cards

#2 sounds like

> A game of craps.

#3 might be

> Some kind of brush

I'm fairly sure #4 is

> A purse

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

Number 1 might be a

> Spade

I use my head, I move the earth,

> The head of a shovel (spade) moves dirt

So ancient none recall My birth,

> Shovels seem like they've been around for awhile (Cursory Google search says the Neolithic period / Early Bronze Age)

One of me spells death and yet,

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_of_spades), the Ace of Spades is a "Death Card"

You'd call me as I am I'll bet

> To call a spade a spade

You know me well, you've got my card

> Spades are a common suit in playing cards

Who am I? it isn't hard.

> You're a Spade

I think #3 is a

> mop

A head of thick, wet, braided hair

> Sounds like the business end of a mop

I carry more than can be seen

> Picks up grime off the floor

And in my wake a brightening glare

> Leaves the floor nice and shiny

A slick, treacherous sheen

> But also wet, and easy to slip on

My story short, but often told

> Doesn't take long to do, but should be done often

Me in your hands, what would you hold?

> A mop

Six could be a

> Oath

Comment: Getting there 2/8 +1

Comment: Changed answer to six.  How is my score now?

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. It'd be great if we could change my answer to a Community Wiki, so everyone can add their explanations and get credit.

Answer (score 4):

Number 2 has got to be:

> Yahtzee

Dice will roll,

> It's a dice game.

Name and goal the same,

> Yahtzee is the name of the game, as well as what you are trying to get.

I have two kinds,

> It has two "kind" spaces (three and four of a kind).

And just one chance,

> It one chance space where any kind of result can be placed.

Comment: Getting there 1/8 +1