# I was inspired by an addiction to riddles

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

Inspired by this [Addicted to Riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70172/addicted-to-riddles) puzzle by @[BrentHackers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22895/brent-hackers), I have created my own addicted to riddles puzzle. So...

*How do you know if you're addicted to riddles?*

---

1.

> *My silky feathers serve a rest,* 
>  
>   *Beneath a gentle crown of dreams.* 
>  
>   *The eight hours I manifest,* 
>  
>   *Is often quicker than it seems.*

2.

> *I am the wool of a sheep,* 
>   *But I cannot ever be sheared.* 
>  
>   *I can be found never deep,* 
>  
>   *Unless when thoughts have appeared.*

3.

> *I am the shield of a mind,* 
>   *Bringing death to the heart;* 
>  
>   *I am a sword for pirate kind,* 
>  
>   *Showing life for a mortal start.*

4.

> *As the present of the past,* 
>   *I am still, but never idle.* 
>   *Your mem’ry may not last,* 
>   *Thus, I keep it with a smile.*

5.

> *I thank the trees as a pencil’s friend,* 
>   *So pale though never in fright.* 
>   *In shedding a tear, I will likely bend,* 
>   *Though eyes only earn my despite.*

---

*What do all of these riddles have in common?*

There are two answers: the obvious one, and the not-so-obvious one.

**HINT RIDDLE:** $\;\dagger$

> *I’m made of glass, this much is true;* 
>  *But when you look, you won’t see through;* 
>  *When there is one, I can make two;* 
>  *Reflect on this to find a clue!*

$\dagger$.

> <sub>**This riddle is not mine**. <s>I will credit the source of the riddle after it has been solved in order to not spoil the answer, for those who wish to look at the hint.</s> It can be found [here](http://riddlesandanswers.treasurehuntriddles.org/Tags/mirror).</sub>

**SECOND HINT RIDDLE:**

> *When together, we might have a spine, 
>  On a shelf, though we have not one bone. 
>  Either blank, with a graph or a line, 
>  I'm a sheet with no cotton to own. 
>  
>  The last answer is what I define, 
>  But it might just already be known; 
>  And although I've a simple design, 
>  Via me complex art might be shown.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are: 
1

> Pillow. Eight hours of sleep go by rather quickly.

2

> Wool-gathering credit to Mohirl. Also known as "preoccupation" or "inattention".

3

> Skull. "Shield of the mind" as it protects our brain. And pirates are usually depicted with a skull. It strikes fear into the hearts of others and maybe that is a metaphorical sword?

4

> The answer is "Still" a synonym of photograph. Logic credited to Gareth

5

> An eraser (Also known as a rubber ). "Friend of pencils" as it erases the mistakes made by them. Bends in shedding a tear, this can either mean bending while erasing a drawing of a tear or it can tear the paper if used too roughly. And lastly "Eyes earn my despite", poking holes into them to make eyes only ruin it.

Thanks to Gareth and Mohirl. These should fit the answers in the riddle with the hint

> Mirror

Comment: Doh! I was thinking that for #3 but I somehow failed to link it to pirates

Comment: Haha. But the hint confuses me. How is it useful? Unless it's just there to confuse us. But there are two answers to this as per the question. It's not over yet.

Comment: If you pick a synonym for #5 then all these answers contain doubled letters. (As does "riddles", of course.)

Comment: Hmm in that case I changed the 5th. But 2 and 4, I have no idea.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You're right! Still no idea about the wool riddle though.. Though I gave a try

Comment: The 2nd, 4th and 5th answers are incorrect, but the 5th one can work (at least for the obvious theme). But what do all the answers share in common? :D

Comment: @user477343 they all contain a double letter.

Comment: Wow, that has to be a sheer coincidence! Man... I must have subconsciously done that... That was not what I intended, but it definitely works, hahah! Nice observation!!

Comment: That wasn't my observation lol. @GarethMcCaughan said that XD

Comment: Oh. Well, nice observation, then, @GarethMcCaughan! heheh

Comment: The only problem thus far is the "thanking the trees" part (that still needs explaining) and @Mohirl 's guess is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: @user477343 can you provide us with another hint?

Comment: Okay, I have added a hint! Jeez, it took an hour?? Wow, time flies...

Comment: @user477343 The second hint, is it an rot13(obbx)??

Comment: No, it isn't. It is close. Those have spines on their *own*... the hint tells of something that has spines when *together*... but you are on the right track! :D

Comment: rot13 ( Cntrf bs n obbx? Orpnhfr jura lbh chg gur cntrf gbtrgure bayl gura vg sbezf n obbx fb gurersber jura gur cntrf ner gbtrgure gurl unir n fcvar. Naq ab obar jura nybar.)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see this comment earlier. (Make sure to put @[username you are commenting to] in your comment(s).) Yes, that is the answer. $\ast$ (ROT13) gur npghny nafjre vf cncre (orpnhfr gurer pna or "tencu" cncre naq "oynax" cncre naq "yvar" cncre, abg arprffnevyl sbe cntrf, gubhtu), $\ast$ but your answer is close enough so I will give you that. Also, the Rot13("zrgncubevpny fjbeq") in the explanation of 3. is just part of the Rot13(Wbyyl Ebtre cvengr synt) and the answer to 2. is a Rot13(pybhq).  Why am I revealing this? Because your answer is sufficient $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ :D

Comment: @user477343 aye thanks. Should I edit it then or leave it as it is?

Comment: Whatever you want. I suggest probably editing it if you potentially want more upvotes (mine being excluded, because I already upvoted :P) :D

Answer (score 2):

Theese are probably the obvious ones!

1. My silky feathers serve a rest, 
   Beneath a gentle crown of dreams. 
   The eight hours I manifest, 
   Is often quicker than it seems.

> Obviously something to do with sleep - a **pillow** is generally made of feathers and lies "Beneath a gentle crown of dreams"

**2. I am the wool of a sheep, 
But I cannot ever be sheared. 
I can be found never deep, 
Unless when thoughts have appeared.**

Missing this one as answer confirmed wrong

> Fairly sure this is wrong, but **woolgathering** is absent minded, aimless thought - which obviously can't be sheared

3. I am the shield of a mind, 
   Bringing death to the heart; 
   I am a sword for pirate kind, 
   Showing life for a mortal start.

Thanks to @R.D., this is

> **Skull**

4. As the present of the past, 
   I am still, but never idle. 
   Your mem’ry may not last, 
   Thus, I keep it with a smile.

> A **photograph**? People generally smile in it, and it's a memento of the past that may outlast a memory

5. I thank the trees as a pencil’s friend, 
   So pale though never in fright. 
   In shedding a tear, I will likely bend, 
   Though eyes only earn my despite.

   > **Paper** thanks trees since that's where it comes from, and is usually pale.

Hint 1 seems fairly obviously

> A **mirror**.

Hint 2 part 1:

> Books

Comment: Yes, the 2nd answer is incorrect. But all the others are correct. You haven't answered 3. though! Anyway, once you figure out 2., what do all the answers have in common?

Comment: Yes, @R.D is right. $\ast$ (ROT13) gur fjbeq cneg ersref gb gur fxhyy naq fjbeq (be obarf) ba n cvengr synt; v.r., gur wbyyl ebtre. $\ast$ :D

Comment: Yes, Hint 1 is correct, but Hint 2 is not. "When *together* we might have a spine." That also does not explain the "graph, line, blank" part. Close, though :P